# is it possible to have ingress tls without hostname?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am new to kubernetes and my question could be naive.

I am working for client and i installed JupyterHub on Google Kubernetes Engine. To be able to access it from client side externally I used ingress with TLS & hostname `https://my-jupyterhub/jhub` and everything is working fine.

Now my client doesn't want to use DNS/hostname for some reasons and want to access the jupyterhub using the IP address only.

Is it possible to have TLS without hostname in ingress? If No, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can achieve this by connecting through the External IP of the cluster and serving the Jupyter hub on the port you want and open that port.

You can of course set an static IP on the cluster so it stays the same, you can find information on that regard on the following links [1] [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#reservedaddress

[2] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip